# the added result (for loop) is not as expected

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a calculator, which input a number n it can automatically output the sum of
1/2+2/2 +1/3+2/3+3/3 +...+1/n+2/n+...+n/n and for each denominator, print the result once.
The calculator will restart and ask for input after output the final result of 1/2+2/2 +1/3+2/3+3/3 +...+1/n+2/n+...+n/n .And when the the user decides to stop the program enter 0.

**for input=3 ,the output is sum =1 ,sum=2  ,yet I expected it to be sum=3/2, sum=7/2**

Here's the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    printf("Please enter the max denominator：\n");  
    
    int i,j,n;
    int sum=0;
    do{
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for (j=2;j<=n;j++){
            for(i=1;i<=j;i++){
                sum+= i/j;
            
                if (i==j){
                printf("sum=%d\n",sum);
                break;
                }
            }
        
        }
    } while (n!=0);
   
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:  revised part due to advice

```
int i,j,n;
double sum=0.0;
do{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    sum=0.0;
    for (j=2;j<=n;j++){
        for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
            sum+=(double)i/j;
        printf("sum=%lf\n",sum);
        }
    
} while (n!=0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use floating point arithmetic — `double` values.  With `sum+= i/j;` where `i` and `j` are both integers, you will get `0` as the result of the division every time.  Even `sum` is an `int`.

Comment: Without knowing exactly how you changed things, it is hard to know what's going on in your revised code.  Using `double sum = 0.0;` for the declaration is necessary.  Using `sum += (double) i / j;` or equivalent should help with the rest.  It's not obvious why you have the `if` in the inner loop; the inner loop will end after the iteration where `i == j` anyway; the `printf()` statement could (probably should) go outside the inner loop, at the end of the outer loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is working with integers.  `i`, `j`, `n`, and `sum` are all integers.  This means they cannot encode numbers like 3/2 or 7/2.

So what happens when you divide two integers, like `1/2`?  The answer is that the result rounds down to the nearest integer.  Since `1/2` is 0.5, the nearest integer below that is 0, so the result is 0.

You need to use `float`, which uses floating point arithmetic.  Floating point arithmetic has its own set of [fun rounding issues](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/) (You may be surprised to find that "0.2" cannot be represented exactly with floating point numbers).

A more exact alternative is to write your own functions to handle rational numbers as a pair of integers -- a numerator and a denominator.  It will require additional algorithms (such as a Greatest Common Divisor algorithm), but it can describe these sorts of problems exactly.

Comment: Using `float` is usually a bad idea compared with using `double` — the accuracy of `float` types is much more limited.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That could be looked at later.  For the present problem, float and double will have the same issues, so you could use one or the other.